# MySQL Crashed, innodb trying to access page number which is outside the tablespace bounds

Tags: mysql, database, recovery

I am running MySQL (5.7) on a Windows 2012 server. One of the table (> 1 million records) seems to be corrupted. The mysql error log shows

```
2019-01-16T09:41:09.256990Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190116 14:41:09
2019-01-16T09:41:25.153201Z 2 [Warning] IP address 'ip' could not be resolved: No such host is known. 
2019-01-16T09:41:25.620502Z 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Trying to access page number 3 in space 470, space name shop/products, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type read. If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the MySQL server.
2019-01-16T09:41:25.623268Z 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Server exits.
```

This issue raised when I was inserting records in this table. This table have 22 indexed columns and one of them is FULLTEXT.

I have also tried innodb_force_recovery = [1 - 6], but I am not able to dump the products table. Whenever I tried to access this table it crashes the DB server.

is there any way to get dump or recover this table. I have old dated backup so I can't use that one. Thanks :)

**MYSQL Server Details:**

- Version 5.7 (32 bit)
- Windows Server 2012
- Database Engine: InnoDB

**Updated**

I am facing the strange issue. When I execute the table status command it shows the rows count is zero,

but products.ibd file size is 4GB in mysql data folder.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM shop LIKE 'products';
```

[image]

**File size by OS**

[image]

Comment: The simplest solution would be to restore that table from a backup if you have one

Comment: Sorry that is the issue, I don't have updated backup. It will be the last option for me to restore the old backup. :)

Comment: this question is beter suited for https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It sounds like your file may have been corrupted in one of the header pages instead of a data page. InnoDB files contain a number of pages that only store metadata about how to find the data pages within the file. If the metadata pages are corrupted, I don't have any idea how you can read the table at all. Cf. https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/03/the-basics-of-innodb-space-file-layout/

Comment: The best MySQL data recovery experts I know of are https://twindb.com. You can try consulting with them.

Comment: If you have an old backup, but you have continuous binary logs from the time you made the backup until present, you could do [point-in-time recovery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/point-in-time-recovery.html). In other words, restore the old backup, and then replay the events in the binary log (I'd recommend doing this on another server).

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for guidance. should I restore whole DB or the single table?

Comment: You'll need to restore the whole DB so you can replay the binary logs. There's no easy way to separate binlog events for each table. Read the point-in-time recovery docs I linked to. Note you will also need to know what the binlog position was at the time you made that backup. If you didn't record the binlog position with the backup, you won't be able to use this solution because you won't know what part of the binlog to restore.